# Conditions for Alternating Series to Converge to Zero

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, analysis

Suppose we have a sequence $(a_n)$ of real numbers where $a_n$ are either equal to zero or they are all distinct for all $n \geq 1$.

Further suppose that the following series is such that $$ \sum_{n=1} ^\infty a_n (-1)^n = 0$$

Does it immediately imply that we must then have that $a_n = 0$ for all $n \geq 1$?
Or is it possible to have such an alternating series which is equal to zero, where some of the terms $a_n$ are non-zero and distinct?

I have tried coming up with counterexamples and I can't seem to find any. So I feel it's true.
When attempting to prove it, I have tried to do some sort of grouping argument, basically arguing that there has to be some sort of a pattern of cancellation that occurs, but since all $a_n$ are distinct, you cannot have them all cancel out. But I can't seem to make the argument rigorous, which is also why I'm wary it might not be true.

If anyone has any ideas I would appreciate it!

Comment: Consider two convergent series of positive terms $\sum b_n, \sum c_n$ with the same sum.  Then let $a_{2n}=b_n$ and $a_{2n-1}=c_n$.  An example might be $b_n=\frac 1{2^n}$ and $c_n=\frac 2{3^n}$.

Comment: Note:  such a series can't pass the Leibniz test (terms decrease to $0$)), since for any series that passes that test, the final sum must lie between $a_1$ and $a_1-a_2$, hence it is $>0$.  Note that the example I constructed, while convergent, is certainly not decreasing.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To summarize the comments:

Such sequences are easily produced.  Take any two positive series that converge to the same sum, then intertwine them.

Specific example: let $b_n=\frac 1{2^n}$ and $c_n=\frac 2{3^n}$

Then both $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} b_n$ and $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} c_n$ converge to $1$.

Then we let $a_{2n}=b_n$ and $a_{2n-1}=c_n$.  The resultant alternating series $\sum (-1)^na_n$ converges absolutely, hence we can rearrange the terms freely, so the series converges to $0$.

Note: it is easy to check that $b_n\neq c_m$ for any pair $(n,m)$.

We remark that the sequence $\{a_n\}$ is not decreasing (the even values are considerable larger than the nearby odd values for large $n$).   Indeed, if the alternating sequence passed the Leibniz test for conditional convergence, it could not sum to $0$ (standard arguments show that the sum would lie between $a_1$ and $a_1-a_2$, hence would be $>0$.